# Candy machine not found despite all transactions successful

Tags: sugar, candymachine

I have deployed candy machine, but cannot find despite all trsactions being successful..

./sugarCM3 deploy
[1/3]  Loading candy machine
⚠️  Candy machine FTg17PM9Vs1nc3NALB8gyZCjnzfrWmK7z4Yb6YXHcQBo not found on-chain
⚠️  This can happen if the deploy transaction fails or times out
  Creating candy machine
Candy machine ID: G35sh5XpBuP9TWTfJeAp5rPByxwTLHwhJCysTLPpcot6

[2/3]  Creating and setting the collection NFT for candy machine
Collection mint ID: 9eHy2XftNXuNndMj1ufQ2z81ovBwAfFpY5qaZY5BssuV

[3/3]  Writing config lines
Sending config line(s) in 125 transaction(s): (Ctrl+C to abort)
[00:00:15] Write config lines successful ███████████████████████████████ 125/125

✅ Command successful.

https://solscan.io/account/G35sh5XpBuP9TWTfJeAp5rPByxwTLHwhJCysTLPpcot6

But saloneys says account not found

https://www.solaneyes.com/address/G35sh5XpBuP9TWTfJeAp5rPByxwTLHwhJCysTLPpcot6

Can any advise whats going on ?

Answer (score 2):

Your Candy Machine has been deployed successful, it is just an issue with solaneyes. If you take a look at the network tab, it shows that solaneyes uses https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net/ as its RPC, which has been deprecated. If you want to inspect the Candy Machine's data, you can check it over here - https://solana.fm/address/G35sh5XpBuP9TWTfJeAp5rPByxwTLHwhJCysTLPpcot6/anchor-account?cluster=mainnet-qn1

[image: network tab of solaneyes]